# uncompress html source code using terminal

Tags: html, linux, bash, terminal

some website source code is compressed and in one line.
which i want in default HTML structured. Can i do with terminal?
I want to do it with wget command.
i use online tool textFixer. But i want to do it with terminal.

i want one line text into default HTML structure using terminal or using script.

http://www.sawfirst.com/

is example of one line compressed source code.

i want to one line source code to default HTML structured.

Comment: What is "default HTML structure"? Sounds like you could pipe the HTML into a formatting tool but it depends on the format you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Is it about how to automatically indent a text file ? If so you could have a look at [html tidy](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are able to utilize php you could do something like

```
curl URL | php -r '$s = ""; while($l = fgets(STDIN)) {$s .= $l;} $x=new DOMDocument(); $x->loadHTML($s); $x->preserveWhiteSpace = false; $x->formatOutput = true; echo $x->saveHTML();'
```

saveHTML seems to not insert leading white spaces (for improved indentation), but saveXML does, so you can use $x->saveXML() instead.

That will most likely result in many warnings, so you might want to change it to:

```
curl URL | php -r 'error_reporting(E_ERROR); $s = ""; while($l = fgets(STDIN)) {$s .= $l;} $x=new DOMDocument(); $x->loadHTML($s); $x->preserveWhiteSpace = false; $x->formatOutput = true; echo $x->saveXML();'
```

Of course you can provide the script within your `$PATH` to make it more simple

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$input = call_user_func(function(){
    $lines = [];
    while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) {
        $lines[] = $line;
    }
    return implode("\n", $lines);
});

$domDocument = new DomDocument();
$domDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;
$domDocument->loadHTML($input);

echo $domDocument->saveXML();
```

And save that file for example to `/usr/local/bin/phphtmltidy` and make it executeable (`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phphtmltidy`)

Then you could simply:

```
curl URL | phphtmltidy
```

Of course you could also use node as interpreter and work with a library like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltidy)